# Regular Expression for Matching String not beginning or ending with alphabet

Tags: java, regex

Hi I am looking out for Regular Expression to match a String such that it doesn't start or end with a alphabet or number or _ Underscore.

I tried following but doesn't seem to work.

```
public class Test {
    public static final String EXAMPLE_TEST = "This is my MyText example string which I'm going to use for pattern matching.";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\W*)(\\D*)" + "MyText" + "(\\W*)(\\D*)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(EXAMPLE_TEST);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
            System.out.print(" End index: " + matcher.end() + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

---

I tried following but doesn't seem to work.

```
Desired o/p = 5
Current Result = 0
```

sample code:

```
public class Test {

    public static final String EXAMPLE_TEST = "#myText myTExT myText!@ Test nmyText myText test";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] array = EXAMPLE_TEST.split(" ");
        int count = 0;
        for(String line : array){
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\W)MyText(?=\\W)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

How ever if I use a Single String as

```
public static final String EXAMPLE_TEST = "#myText myTExT myText!@ Test nmyText myText test";
```

with a while statement I get desired o/p as 5.

```
    while(matcher.find()){
            count++;
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```

In this case output is 5 as expected.

Comment: "*doesn't seem to work*" is not right problem description. Add more details about what you expected and what you got instead so we could help you easier and people with similar problem would also be able to find your question and read answers to it.

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: I am trying to search a text pattern in String, where I am searching for MyText, but "MyText" should not begin with any other alphabet or number or _, space and other symbols are allowed.

Comment: If you updates your original code and question then it discards all the answer that is posted as per your previous post. Please add it in the last and keep original post as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am searching for MyText, but MyText should not begin with any other alphabet or number or _, space and other symbols are allowed

To me it looks like simple word boundary will do the job, i.e. this regex:

```
\bMyText\b
```

Comment: You're right, that comment that you quoted has really changed the question into something completely different.

Comment: Yes sometimes reading OP's mind in these regex question is pretty tricky :)

Comment: *other symbols are allowed* what about this?

Comment: `\b` does allow other symbols like space, hyphen etc.

Comment: pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bMyText\\b",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);







This worked for me. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked. Yes indeed in Java `\b` is written as `\\b`.

Answer (score 2):

> match a String such that it doesn't start or end with a alphabet or number or _ Underscore.

You can try with [**Positive Lookaround**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
(?<=\W)MyText(?=\W)
```

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/sV9nA8/1)

---

You can use `[^\w]` instead of `\W` in above regex pattern

- `\W` match any non-word character `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`
- `\w` match any word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

---

As per comments

```
String EXAMPLE_TEST = "It fails for following text #myText myTExT myText!@ Test myText myText test.";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\W)MyText(?=\\W)",
        Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(EXAMPLE_TEST);
while (matcher.find()) { // <--- Look Here, use while instead of if
    System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
    System.out.print(" End index: " + matcher.end() + " ");
    System.out.println(" Match String: " + matcher.group() + " ");
}
```

output:

```
Start index: 29 End index: 35  Match String: myText 
Start index: 36 End index: 42  Match String: myTExT 
Start index: 43 End index: 49  Match String: myText 
Start index: 57 End index: 63  Match String: myText 
Start index: 64 End index: 70  Match String: myText
```

---

Lots of EDIT by OP in the original post

If you are doing split then it become a single word in that case use

```
Pattern.compile("(?<=\\W|^)MyText(?=\\W|$)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Comment: this is working well in http://regex101.com/. But in my java when I use it as 
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\W)my text(?=\\W)",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

It fails for following text 
#myText
myTExT
myText!@
Test myText
myText test.

It 3 shows only two matches for 

if(matcher.find()){
 count++
}

O/P is 3, wheras all above are valid.

Comment: Sorry my bad...the o/p is O and not 3

Comment: In above example it returns 5 matches. Is it wrong? If yes then what is not expected output?

Comment: the Java version returns 0.
The one http://regex101.com/r/sV9nA8/1 here returns 5 which is expected.

Comment: replace the string in the sample code. Here is [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sV9nA8/2) You might forget to use `i` modifier for case-insensitive. Test it in code and use `while(matcher.find())` to match all.

Comment: Hi 
Thanks for response really appreciate it.
I get correct results online at http://regex101.com/r/sV9nA8/1. Result as 5 Matches.

But same regex when I use in java for same text, it doesnot matach and output is 0 in Java Code.

I use Pattern and Matcher.

Pattern pattern = pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\W)myText(?=\\W)",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
if(matcher.find()){
count++;
}

I als tried 
while(matcher.find()) same result 0.

Comment: use `while()` instead of `if()`. Updated code in post.

Comment: hey I tried and Updated the question, can You please help. I used array here coz I am reading it as read line using burrferdReader from file. Same problem when I use array Thanks :)

Comment: If you are doing an split based on comma then pattern will work in the case. I don't know what do you want to achieve. Why don't you try my code? Is there any issue with my code?

Comment: I Tried, split based on coma, blank spaces, even reading it from file....But I get it 0 all time.  How ever I provide a single string containing 5 matches and iterate using while() it gices me expected result.

Comment: post updated but I don't feel happy because original post is lost somewhere and you have added answer in your question it self. As per your new sample code. It will match only 4.

Comment: Hey Thanks for response and time really appreciate it. 
The following worked well for me    pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bMyText\\b",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this:

```
^\W.*\W$
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/nU2gW9/2)**

[image]

Btw, if you want to grab the content you can use capturing groups:

```
^\W(.*)\W$
```